# How to add one project to another one and use all properties of the added project in c#(windows form)

Tags: c#

I have two projects (project1 and project2), I have added project2 to project1 by just adding  as (add existing project) and now I have two projects in the same solution explorer.

My question is how can I use or access preject2 in project1, I would like to call project2 main form in project 1 something like this:

```cs
project2mainform p2m = new project2mainform ();
p2m.show();
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Add Project reference.

Comment: import namespace

Comment: I did that , when calling it says (it is namespace but use like a type somehting)

Comment: Please add the relevant code. Looks and feels like a simple typo.

Comment: Does the Second Project/a namespace is named exact like the class you want to instantiate? that would explain your exception.

Comment: Yes, it is same